# Lambda - Is there a way to conditionally switch between Unreserved and Reserved concurrency in serverless templates?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am using serverless template to create a lambda function in AWS.

If I don't specify any value for the property "ReservedConcurrentExecutions", then the function gets created with Unreserved concurrency.

Now, I would like to use reserved concurrency (or unreserved) depending on an input parameter.

Function with Reserved Concurrency:

```
 "MyFunction": {
      "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Properties": {
          "Handler": "MyFunctionHandler",
          "CodeUri": "myfunction.zip",
          "ReservedConcurrentExecutions" : 2,               
       }
  }
```

Function with Unreserved Concurrency: (just don't use the ReservedConcurrentExecutions property)

```
 "MyFunction": {
      "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
      "Properties": {
          "Handler": "MyFunctionHandler",
          "CodeUri": "myfunction.zip",               
       }
  }
```

I know I can declare the 2 functions separately and have a Condition to create one or the other.

What I would like to know is if it is possible to have just one function and conditionally add the ReservedConcurrentExecutions property.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Serverless framework does not support conditional statements and properties to resources, but you can try and use this ["ifelse" plugin](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-plugin-ifelse).